# Is $2^{2^m-2}+1$ always a composite number for $m>2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Is $2^{2^m-2}+1$ always a composite number for $m>2$ ?

I really don't have any idea how to prove or disprove this , it is given to me that it is true . Since nothing else is coming to my mind , I tried to prove it by induction but it was not useful .
Could someone please guide me how to prove this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hint: $2^m-2$ has an odd factor $d$. Your number is of the form $a^d+1$.

Comment: $2^n+1$ for $n\ge 2$ can only be prime if $n$ is a power of $2$. This is not the case here.

Comment: @Peter , how did you conclude that ? Could you please elaborate or link me to any site or page which elaborates it .

Comment: @Wojowu , Got it , it will always be divisible by 5 (4+1) , thanks !

Comment: Otherwise $n$ has an odd prime factor and Wojowu's hint can be applied.

Comment: @Peter , got it , thanks !

Comment: $2^{2^m-2}+1=4^{2^{m-1}-1}+1\equiv (-1)^{2^{m-1}-1}+1 = -1+1=0 \pmod{5}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any *odd* n, n>1, we have

$$ 2^{2n}+1 = (2^n+1)^2 - \big(2^{(n+1)/2}\big)^2 = \big( 2^n+2^{(n+1)/2}+1 \big) \big( 2^n-2^{(n+1)/2}+1 \big). $$

Moreover

$$ 2^n+2^{(n+1)/2}+1 > 2^n-2^{(n+1)/2}+1 = 2^{(n+1)/2}\big( 2^{(n-1)/2}-1 \big) + 1 > 1 $$

for $n>1$.

Therefore, $2^{2n}+1$ is composite whenever $n$ is odd and $n>1$.

In the given problem, $n=2^{m-1}-1$ is odd, and $m>2$ translates to $n>1$. $\blacksquare$